# Dart Polymer 1.0 - Two-way binding works?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Two-way binding works in Dart Polymer 1.0 - RC2?

When I change the field @Property(nofity: true) in the .dart, it does not reflect (change) into  {{}} in the .html.

See the following example.

Whem I click on paper-button, it´s fire *clicar*, the property *text* is changed, but   *{{text}}* does not change!

**main_app.html**

```
<dom-module id="main-app">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

  <template>
    <paper-input label="Type something..." value="{{text}}"></paper-input>
    <p>
      Text: <span>{{text}}</span><br />
    </p>
    <paper-button on-click="clicar">cliqueme</paper-button>
    </p>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

**main_app.dart**

```
@HtmlImport('main_app.html')
library untitled8.lib.main_app;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_button.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';

@PolymerRegister('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @Property(notify: true)
  String text;

  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  @reflectable
  void clicar(e, detail) {
    text = "super teste";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the provided methods to updated properties like

```
 set('text', "super teste");
```

`notify: true` is only to notify parent elements (fires an `test-changed` event)

There are quite a lot such methods in `PolymerBase` mixin which you get automatically added by extending `PolymerElement` and which notify Polymer about changes.

- `notifyPath` (currently the same as `set`)

for collections there are

- `add`
- `addAll`
- `clear`
- `fillRange`
- `insert`
- `insertAll`
- `removeItem`
- `removeAt`
- `removeLast`
- `removeRange`
- `removeWhere`
- `replaceRange`
- `retainWhere`
- `setAll`
- `setRange`

there is also a

- `get`

not sure about what to use it for.