# binding attributes and properties in polymer 1.0

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0

I'm learning Dart and Polymer 1.0 but I am stuck with bindings in polymer. I prepared project in a GitHub repository. You can see it [here](https://github.com/JLeenk/binding.git) . 
Can me explain what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have private properties in Dart. Reflection (mirrors, reflectable) don't support accessing private members. Remove the leading `_` from the property names.

When you update the value of a property use the Polymer API like

```
set('secondComponent', 'component2');
```

See [Dart Polymer 1.0 - Two-way binding works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170456) for more details

Comment: Interesting. I removed an underscore from a property name and run a set method for update property  but attribute in first component doesn't react on changes. I thought that attribute can bind property between first and second component.

Comment: Time for bed, I look again tomorrow. If the parent element needs to get notified you might need `@Property(notify: true) String someProperty;`. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties

Comment: Ok, this approach works when we need to pass value from child to parent but it doesn't work vice versa. I tried use @Property(reflectToAttribute: true) but it doesn't work perhaps I do some thing wrong. Is there any way pass a  property value from parent to child element? I corrected my project https://github.com/JLeenk/binding.git.

Comment: You don't need to assign the value to the field **and** call `set(...)`.  `set(...)` alone is enough. `reflectToAttribute` is only to have the attribute and its value available in the DOM, for example when you want to use it in a CSS selector.

Comment: If you use `@HtmlImport()`, you don't need any imports like https://github.com/JLeenk/binding/blob/master/lib/test_components/first_component/first_component.html#L1, just import the Dart file from the 2nd component in the Dart file of 1st component.

Comment: I just checked out your repo and applied my suggestions and everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Yes, after applying your suggestions now everything is working properly. Thank you.